# Нужна помощь с регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно регуляркой найти следующие совпадения в строке и сделать замену

Строка имеет вид:

```
[STRING_*****] (STRING_*****) /STRING/PATH
```

Так вот нужно найти все вхождения `[STRING` и `(STRING` кроме `/STRING`

Попробовал но пока не очень получается: `\[STRING|\(STRING` таким образом захватывает и скобки,мне же нужно только `STRING`

Comment: Так не пойдёт, задавайте новый вопрос

Comment: Имеете в виду переписать полностью вопрос?

Comment: Я уже дал ответ =) не вовремя вы это затеяли.

Comment: @quaresma89, имею в виду, что вы изменили суть вопроса. Из-за этого два ответа ниже выглядят нерелевантно. Для новых вопросов здесь есть большая кнопка ["Задать вопрос"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

[RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

```js
let str='[STRING_****1] (STRING_****2) /STRING/PATH';
let pattern = /[\[(]([^_]*)/g;
let match;
while (match = pattern.exec(str)){
  console.log(match[1], match[0]);
}
```

Или:

```js
let str='[STRING_****1] (STRING_****2) /STRING/PATH';
let pattern = /(?:[\[(])(STRING_[^\])]*)/g;
let match;
while (match = pattern.exec(str)){
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Хм.. Не люблю `exec`. А вот регулярки у нас одинаковые получились :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я так понял, ему нужно исключить скобки. Так что exec)

Comment: Протестил тут https://regex101.com регулярку для php,но чет не находит вхождения вообще

Comment: Ну товарищ, теги нужно релевантные указывать) [Вот](https://regex101.com/r/5p64ny/2)

Comment: Теперь то что надо,спасибо!

Comment: Еще вопрос.Почему при использовании функции preg_replace в строке заменяется [STRING_ на NEW_STRING скобка и нижнее подчеркивание тоже заменяется.

Comment: Напишите новый вопрос с тегом php и с необходимостью замены. Вообще нужно [так](https://regex101.com/r/5p64ny/3) - смотреть поле `substitution`

Answer (score 1):

По идее, так:

```
[\[(]STRING
```

Ну и дополненный пример, который ест до скобки:

```js
console.log("[STRING_*****] (STRING_*****) /STRING/PATH".match(/[\[(]STRING.*?[\])]/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
$str = '[STRING_*****] (STRING_*****) /STRING/PATH';
$str = preg_replace('/[^\[(]+(?=[_])/', 'NEW_STING', $str);
echo $str;
```

Вывод:
`[NEW_STING_*****] (NEW_STING_*****) /STRING/PATH`
Этой регуляркой, также можно и `NEW_STING`, заменить аналогично `STRING`.